# Using submit button with e.preventDefault() vs a regular button

Tags: javascript

I'm following an MDN article on client-storage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage), and I ran across a snippet of code that I had a question about. The example is supposed to show how to use the Web Storage API for simple data persistence, and so it has us enter a name in a form field in order to save that data and render a personalized greeting that persists across sessions. In order to accept user input, it uses an `<input type="submit">` button and then attaches an event listener on it with `form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`
I've noticed this pattern in quite a few of the articles, and so my question is why should we use a submit button and prevent default submit behavior over just creating a regular button? Are there advantages to each? To be clear, I'm not asking why one should use `<input type="submit">` over `<button>` *in general*; I'm wondering why `<input type="submit">` is used in a situation where submitting is not desired when we have `<button>` or `<input type="button">`.

Comment: You do not need to use a button to submit a form.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you couldn't use either a form submit, a button, or even just a hyperlink.  HTML allows you to have input fields without a form, so it should make no difference.  My guess is that it is just the developer's preference.

Answer (score 3):

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

is not binding to a button, but to form submission. Users can submit a form by hitting enter for instance. On mobile devices keyboards might offer similar function. People using assistive technology might have other options too.

This is important because you express intent to the browser.

It can be quite confusing having a form where only the button itself works, but other means you might be used to do not work.

Comment: Oh, I missed that the event was "submit" and not "click". I'm trying to understand so correct me if I'm wrong, whenever the "submit" event is fired, this listener runs a function that prevents default submit behavior (making it so that nothing happens without further code in this case)?

Comment: @embracethefuture Yes. It prevents the browser from sending an HTTP request as would normally be specified by the form attributes method, action etc.